# I keep getting volcano plot despite running script for an expression density plot

Tags: density-plot

we are using
this code here but cant create the exp density instead we get volcano in the "plots" section of R studio please advise on this thank you,Fiona
ggp.exp_density=  ggplot(master,aes(x = log10(gut_r1+0.01))) + geom_density()
labs(x = "Expression (log10)", y = "Density")
ggp

tried the above and expecting exp density plot but actually getting volcano